# Iterate through a folders and subfolders?

Tags: python, loops

Say I have a folder named `people`. Inside that folder there are subfolders `person_1`, `person_2`, `person_3`, etc. Each `person_#` subfolder contains an image of a smiling face (`person_1_happy.png`) and frowning face (`person_1_sad.png`).

Is there a succinct way to use python to iteratively run through each folder and grab only the `person_#_face` images?

Comment: Sure, `names = glob.glob("person_*/dog*.png")`.

Comment: So simple, thank you!!